# Is cmvision a working package?

Tags: ros, cmvision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all, I've noticed that [cmvision](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cmvision) is a package listed on the ROS wiki, but there seems to be no "current" instructions on how to install the code.

I did come across an older clone of the wiki which lists the [package](http://ftp.isr.ist.utl.pt/pub/roswiki/cmvision.html), but that code didn't build:

```
  In file included from /.../ros-stacks/cmvision/src/color_gui.cpp:34:0:
  /.../ros-stacks/cmvision/src/cmvision_color_blob_finder.h:31:32: fatal error: cv_bridge/CvBridge.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  In file included from /.../ros-stacks/cmvision/src/main.cpp:24:0:
  /home/ubuntu/ros-stacks/cmvision/src/cmvision_color_blob_finder.h:31:32: fatal error: cv_bridge/CvBridge.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  In file included from /.../ros-stacks/cmvision/src/color_gui.cpp:34:0:
  /.../ros-stacks/cmvision/src/color_gui.h:34:32: fatal error: cv_bridge/CvBridge.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
```

It looks like opencv has changed a smidge since this package was written so it would need to be updated... Is there an updated repo somewhere else? Has the package been made obsolete by something else? Any pointers?

(And yes I did see [the homebrew post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/hbrobotics/SPafAC0wtM8), but the instructions aren't current either.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56472/is-cmvision-a-working-package?/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2022 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-02-27**:
I think cmvision has been unmaintained for quite some time. I got it working with fuerte a while back, but I don't remember what that required.

**Comment by [Cristina](https://answers.ros.org/users/3909/cristina/) on 2013-03-09**:
I can confirm I am getting the same error when writing an image subscriber like in this tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport/Tutorials/SubscribingToImages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, I've been working with it to track blobs.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/cmvision

http://brown-robotics.org/cs148/doku.php?id=software_environment_setup&#cmvision_color_blob_recognition

http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Detect_Blobs_using_ROS_Package_cmvision

http://brown-robotics.org/cs148/doku.php?id=software_environment_setup&#cmvision_color_blob_recognition

https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/browser/trunk/vision/cmvision/src/cmvision_color_blob_finder.cpp?rev=40760

I'm tracking blobs, now I need to write a node to generate camera tracking, and then on to sending twist messages to the platform.

$ cd <some ros workspace directory>
$ svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/vision/cmvision
$ rospack profile
$ roscd cmvision
$ rosmake --rosdep-install

Alan KM6VV

---

Originally posted by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) with karma: 191 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-02-28**:
Hi Alan, the sources that you suggested were the ones that resulted in the posted error message. What version of ROS were/are you successfully using this package with?

**Comment by [Cristina](https://answers.ros.org/users/3909/cristina/) on 2013-03-09**:
@trinighost I am working in groovy, it seems like CvBridge.h is deprecated in this version and I was able to get rid of the error by using cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h. Of course, now I have other errors, but perhaps you will have more luck!